# Issue with XSLT Transformation: Xml is appearing in plain text after transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

I get the expected Output Xml with part of xml printed as plain text at the end of output xml. 
How can I get rid of plain text xml here?

**Input Xml**

```
<Coverage>
  <CoverageInformation>
    <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
    <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
    <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  </CoverageInformation>
  <RiderInformation>
    <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
    <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
    <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  </RiderInformation>
  <RiderInformation>
    <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
    <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
    <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  </RiderInformation>
</Coverage>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="CoverageInformation">
      <SegmentVO>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="../RiderInformation">
          <SegmentVO>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </SegmentVO>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </SegmentVO>>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Code:**

```
def w = new StringWriter()
        TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                          .newTransformer( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xslt ) ) )
                          .transform( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xmlAsString ) ),
                          new StreamResult( w ) )
        println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( w.toString() )
```

**Output Xml**

```
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in trailing section.'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SegmentVO>
  <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
  <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
  <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
  <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
  <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
  <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
  <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
  <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
  <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
  <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  <SegmentVO>
    <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
    <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
    <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  </SegmentVO>
  <SegmentVO>
    <IssueStateCT>AK</IssueStateCT>
    <OptionCodeCT>ADR</OptionCodeCT>
    <SegmentStatusCT>Frozen</SegmentStatusCT>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/18/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/10/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffectiveDate>09/17/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/16/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
  </SegmentVO>
</SegmentVO>
CT
AggPremium
IssuePendingPremium
08/15/2013
08/15/2013
08/05/2013
08/05/2013
09/19/2013
08/15/2013
09/20/2013


CT
AggPremium
IssuePendingPremium
08/15/2013
08/15/2013
08/05/2013
08/05/2013
09/19/2013
08/15/2013
09/20/2013
```

Comment: You sure that (a) all XML files contain no "funky" characters, e.g., not reasonable ASCII, and (b) were saved with a real text editor, e.g., not MS Word?

Comment: I fixed an extra `>` at line 17 of XSLT but still the same error. Tested Input Xml and Output Xml by opening it in browser and they look fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton Updated Output Xml with trailing section.

Comment: Oh, you're asking why there's extra plain text at the end of your output XML?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve for that input XML?  What is your expected result?

Comment: Expected Result is just `SegmentVO` xml. If you transform it with given code, you should see the expected result. Change return type to `w.toString()` and extra characters will appear.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. I am not about from where these extra characters are appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has default [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) that apply to any nodes for which you haven't specified an explicit template.  Since you've only given a template for the `CoverageInformation` element, any other nodes that have templates applied to them will use the default rules.

The default rule for nodes that have children (e.g. elements) is simply to `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to all the child nodes.  The default rule for text nodes is to print the text to the result tree.  These rules combine in your case to print all the text contained within the `RiderInformation` elements but with the surrounding tags removed.

The simplest fix for this would be to add

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Coverage/CoverageInformation" />
</xsl:template>
```

which will apply templates only to the element(s) you're interested in, and not also apply the default templates to the rest of the document.

Comment: Thank You. I have been stuck with this issue from last 3 days.